# There is any way to add custom fields (checkbox) to a PDF contract dynamically using the Docusign REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

We are generating a PDF contract in out custom code, and then we are sending this PDF file to be signed by the end customer through Docusign REST API.
Thanks works fine. Now we need the customer to fill (or not) some checkboxes inside the PDF file at the same time they are signin the document.
We need to add this checkboxes dynamically from our code, because they are not always the same ones.

I attach an image with an example, we want to do the same we do when we create mannualy a template, but in this case is not inside the template, is inside the document already created outside Docusign.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4wJ7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the auto-place feature.

If you set a specific string of text in your pdf document it will place a tab every time that it finds that text in the document. If you want that text to be hidden from the end user you could use white text on white background.

Here is some info in how this works in the DocuSign UI.

https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/AutoPlace-New-DocuSign-Experience

On the API side they refer to this feature as anchor tabs.

If you want to specify this via the API whenever you create a tab just specify that anchorString value and DocuSign will create a tab for you at each location that it finds the string.

There are a few more properties that allow you to move the anchor tab based on the anchor string so you can define the offsets if you want the tab to be move a specific amount of pixels in the x or y direction.

I hope this helps!

```
"checkboxTabs": [
    {
      "name": "sample string 1",
      "tabLabel": "sample string 2",
      "selected": "sample string 3",
      "shared": "sample string 4",
      "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "sample string 5",
      "required": "sample string 6",
      "locked": "sample string 7",
      "documentId": "sample string 8",
      "recipientId": "sample string 9",
      "pageNumber": "sample string 10",
      "xPosition": "sample string 11",
      "yPosition": "sample string 12",
      "anchorString": "sample string 13",
      "anchorXOffset": "sample string 14",
      "anchorYOffset": "sample string 15",
      "anchorUnits": "sample string 16",
      "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "sample string 17",
      "anchorCaseSensitive": "sample string 18",
      "anchorMatchWholeWord": "sample string 19",
      "anchorHorizontalAlignment": "sample string 20",
      "tabId": "sample string 21",
      "templateLocked": "sample string 22",
      "templateRequired": "sample string 23",
      "conditionalParentLabel": "sample string 24",
      "conditionalParentValue": "sample string 25",
      "customTabId": "sample string 26",
      "mergeField": {},
      "status": "sample string 27",
      "tooltip": "sample string 28",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
      },
      "tabOrder": "sample string 29",
      "tabGroupLabels": [
        "sample string 1"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Hi yadriel, thank you very much. If I understan ok, I just need to create the PDF with some anchorText (in white) like "<PUT_CHECKBOX_HERE>" and then, using this SDK sample I can tell to the DocuSign API to replace this text by a chackbox field, right? How can I get all the fields values after the signature? THANKS!!!

Comment: Hi @Demian, not a problem! After you send the envelope and the user fills all the information you can call the endpoint to get the recipient tabs and that should return all the tabs assigned to that recipient and the values that the recipient set for them. This is the endpoint **GET {vx}/accounts/{accountid}/envelopes/{envelopeid}/recipients/{recipientid}/tabs**